# How to keep the toolbar hidden until my array does not contain null or 0?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to keep the toolbar hidden until my array has no null or 0 in it. But it can have any other number. I tried anding them but it doesn't work either... I'm doing this within an IBAction method So every time it is clicked, it will check the array... Only when it doesn't contain a 0 or null, will the bar toolbar appear...  Am i doing something wrong?

No strings only number values;

This is my logic below.

I initialized my array like this

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < myData.count; ++i)
{
    [arrayData addObject:[NSNull null]];
}



NSNumber *zero = 0;

if ([arrayData containsObject:@"null"] || [arrayData containsObject:zero]) {
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:TRUE];
}
else{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:FALSE animated:TRUE];
}
```

NSLog below

```
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
1,
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>"
```

THANKS!!!

Comment: Are you sure to check arrayData with string "null"?

Comment: It isn't a null string... when I NSLogged it it shows "<null>"

Comment: In your question you say "my array", but in your code you have two arrays, arrayData and rankData. Is that what you want?

Comment: haha sorry was typing too fast... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement should be:

```
if ([arrayData containsObject:[NSNull null]] || [arrayData containsObject:@0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSNumber *zero = 0;`

You are setting the value of the pointer to `0`, making it a pointer to nil. Try `NSNumber *zero = @0;`. `@0` creates an `NSNumber` object with the value `0`.

`[arrayData containsObject:@"null"]` As pointed out by **AKV**, is that what you really want?

Comment: Do you want to check if the array is empty?

Comment: I want to make sure that the array has no values of null or 0... Not if it is empty or not. I already initialized the array by adding a null object.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `no values of null or 0`? `NSArray`s can only contain objects.

Comment: I have an array that is initialized with null objects.
I want to check if they have values or null or 0

Answer (score 0):

`if ([arrayData containsObject:@"null"] || [rankData containsObject:zero])`

containsObject:@"null" -> are you checking for a string with value "null" or checking whether the array is null?

`[arrayData count]==0` or `arrayData==nil` will do the work for second requirement.

---

`[rankData containsObject:zero]` can be written as `[rankData containsObject:@"0"]`